# How to pass parameters to a function through html and access by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my HTML code to switch between the two tabs and display the content accordingly

```
       <div class="tab"  id="tab-1" onclick="switch_tab(1)">
            <a class="tab-text"  href="">ABC</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab" id="tab-2" onclick="switch_tab(2)">
            <a class="tab-text" href="">XYZ</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
          <div id="content-abc"> ... </div>
          <div id="content-xyz"> ... </div>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
        function switch_tab(index) {    
         switch(index) {
          case 1:
              hide_content("content-xyz");
              show_content("content-abc");
              break;
          case 2:
              hide_content("content-abc");
              show_content("content-xyz");
              break;
         }
        }

        function show_content(idname) {
         document.getElementById(idname).style.display = "block";
        }

        function hide_content(idname) {
         document.getElementById(idname).style.display = "none";
        }
```

But it's not working. help.

Comment: What is calling `switch_tab()`?

Comment: switch(index) not index.value

Comment: Look at your console... index is an integer, not an object with a value property. (thus why index.value) doesn't work.

Comment: i corrected it but still not working

Comment: You have no element with id content-xyz

Comment: your click event bind for `div` element, but you click `a` element and never call `switch_tab` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the `<a>` tags with a blank `href` value.  Changing those to "#" (and of course adding the "content" divs) fixes the problem.  You could also get rid of the anchors if they're not needed for styling, since the click event is being handled on the wrapper divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/9p2TM/

Comment: try on this jsfiddle.net/Ge2F7

Comment: This fiddle was using `index.value` instead of simply `index` in the switch statement.  Also, you must switch from "onLoad" to "No wrap - in <head>" on the left if you want the functions to be available at the window scope.  Changing these things results in a working example.

Comment: But this doesn't work on my local machine. What changes should i make? like on jsfiddle, "No wrap-in <head>" was needed instead of "on load"

Comment: the <head> setting on fiddle basically puts the javascript code inside <script> tags in the head of the document, instead of executing the code inside the onLoad method of the page.  I'm not sure what is wrong with your local test, but it could be the location of the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any elements with the ids you've used in your hide_content or show_content functions

Answer (score 0):

You should set the onclick property with JS DOM.  Set the index through the ID Like this:
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

```
for (var i = 0, il = divs.length; i < il; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener("click", createHandler(divs[i], true));
}
```

Full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JBL95/